# How to download multiple files with a wildcard pattern using webclient DownloadFile?

Tags: vb.net

How to download multiple files with a wildcard pattern using webclient DownloadFile? Like project* from https://www.xyz.com.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate over the list of files from a URL as there is no way to 'retrieve a list of files' from an arbitrary URL.   You could have the webserver create a JSON/XML result of all files and you could then parse that?